# Video size different than it should be

Tags: video, size, resolution

I have a video and when I put it through MediaInfo it shows me that its size is 720x576:

```
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
```

But on the screen when height is 576px, the actual width of it is 790px (measured with a program ruler). Why?

p. s. it's not a buggy program because MediaPlayer also shows 720x576 in properties.

Answer (score 0):

The aspect ratio of the encoded pixels may be different than the aspect ratio of the pixels on your monitor.